# How to add relational table in model to show in MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I am trying to show data in view with my model,

I have three tables Region , City and Tribe.

**Tribe**

```
TribeId  Pk
TribeName
CityId
```

**Region**

```
RegionId pk
RegionName
```

**City**

```
CityId
CityName
RegionId
```

Entity Framework classes:

```
public partial class Region
{
    public Region()
    {
        this.Cities = new HashSet<City>();
    }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public City()
    {
          this.Asserahs = new HashSet<Asserah>();
          this.Tribes = new HashSet<Tribe>();
    }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asserah> Asserahs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tribe> Tribes { get; set; }
}

public class Tribe
{
    public Tribe()
    {
        this.Asserahs = new HashSet<Asserah>();
    }

    public int TribeId { get; set; }
    public string TribeName { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asserah> Asserahs { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

My model is like,

```
public class TribeModel : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Tribe> Tribes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

I use scaffolding to create CRUD operation for Tribe.

Controller is like:

```
 public class TribesController : Controller
    {
        private StructureEntities db = new StructureEntities();

        // GET: Tribes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tribes = db.Tribes.Include(t => t.City);
            return View(tribes.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Tribes/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tribe tribe = db.Tribes.Find(id);
            if (tribe == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tribe);
        }

        // GET: Tribes/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "CityName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Tribes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TribeId,TribeName,CityId")] Tribe tribe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tribes.Add(tribe);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "CityName", tribe.CityId);
            return View(tribe);
        }

        // GET: Tribes/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tribe tribe = db.Tribes.Find(id);
            if (tribe == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "CityName", tribe.CityId);
            return View(tribe);
        }

        // POST: Tribes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "TribeId,TribeName,CityId")] Tribe tribe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tribe).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "CityName", tribe.CityId);
            return View(tribe);
        }

        // GET: Tribes/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tribe tribe = db.Tribes.Find(id);
            if (tribe == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tribe);
        }

        // POST: Tribes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Tribe tribe = db.Tribes.Find(id);
            db.Tribes.Remove(tribe);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Tribe table has city id that is FK and city id PK in city table it is getting data from that table. City id has FK RegionId that is Pk in Region Table how can i put Region in my model ?

Comment: which controller action are you referring to?

Comment: ActionResult Create

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean, include it in the model?  Do you want to return it to the view or use it in the SelectList?
Anyway, to include the Region with the City, you need to include it or load it.

```
db.Cities.Include("Region")
```

Comment: Yes i want to return it in view for Selectlist on Create function